# How to extract the title which contains 3 or more a's?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I created that code http://paste.ubuntu.com/5730390/ and I'm trying to extract titles which contain 3 or more a's (upercase or lowcase),also α's (greek letter) from some websites. I have already stored on a local hdd the websites content in txt format (there is a large number of websites).

My input in dfs is like: site_1.txt, site_2.txt, site_3.txt etc.

Supose that the titles below belong to site_1.txt,site_2.txt,site_3.txt respectively.

1. Academia.edu - Share research
2. Google
3. News12.gr | Αθλητική Ενημέρωση από τα Δωδεκάνησα

Now I want the output to contains: titles 1 and 3 (3 cause there is greek websites and contains a letter "α") in a form like:

Academia.edu - Share research, site_1.txt

News12.gr | Αθλητική Ενημέρωση από τα Δωδεκάνησα, site_2.txt

I tried regex pattern like "?:[αa{3,}]).*(?:[αa{3}]).*", but there is no results.
Would anyone help with that?

Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match 3 a's or alphas, not necessarily next to each other, you can use this regex:

```
(?:[αa].*){3}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really sound like a hadoop problem, just a regex one.  You just need to match the `a` or alpha 3 or more times.  The following regex will do the trick `"([aα].*){3,}"`.

```
String files[] = {
        "Academia.edu - Share research",
        "Google",
        "News12.gr | Αθλητική Ενημέρωση από τα Δωδεκάνησα"};
String regexpattern = "([aα].*){3,}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexpattern);
for (String file: files){
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file);
    while (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("file name matched '" + file+"'");
    }
}
```

Comment: hi greedybuddha...I tagged hadoop and MR, cause I wasn't sure for whole code, I thought maybe there is another problem with code. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` to achieve this:

```
public static int howMany(String str, char c) {
    String str2 = str.replace(c+"", "");
    return str.length() - str2.length();
}
```

Then you can use above method:

```
for(String website : websites) {
    if(howMany(website, 'a') >= 3 || howMany(website, 'α')) {
        System.println(website);
    }
}
```